In moodle how to create a Stripe subscriptions plan like monthly/yearly?
I want some of the pages of my site should be paid.
So at first I need to scope an option to subscribe monthly/yearly.
And I want to use stripe as a payment gateway.
Any suggestions how can I achieve this in moodle.
I thought to use some courses as subscription plans but there is another limitations of renew of the enrollment.

The Moodle plugins directory has a list of contributed plugins
https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=stripe
The first one in the list is a course enrolment plugin for Stripe
https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_stripepayment
The Pro version ($99) has a subscription plan for weekly/monthly/yearly
https://dualcube.com/product/moodle-stripe-payment-pro/
